# Error message will show if user is already available in the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im validating the textbox whether the values are already available in database or not. in the below code it is working fine also showing alert message(Notification ID Already Available).But If i click ok in the alert box,mouse cursor is going to second textbox.I want Cursor should be in the first textbox itself if i click on the ok button in the alertbox. ANy suggestions.
Please find the code below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function checkValid(){
    var flg="Y";
    $.getJSON( "dynamic_content_values1.json", function( data ){
        var textVal=$("#character_validation").val(); 
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            if(textVal===val.notificationID){
                flg="N";return false;
            }
        });
        if(flg==="N"){
             alert("Notification ID Already Available!");
             //$("#character_validation").focus(''); 
        }
        else{
            alert("Notification ID Available"); 
        }
    return false;
    });
}
</script>
</head> 
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" id="character_validation" onblur="checkValid();" maxlength="10" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g, '')">
<br>
<input type="text">
<!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="checkValid();">-->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im validating the textbox whether the values are already available in database or not. in the below code it is working fine also showing alert message(Notification ID Already Available).But If i click ok in the alert box,mouse cursor is going to second textbox.I want Cursor should be in the first textbox itself if i click on the ok button in the alertbox. ANy suggestions.

Comment: <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> <script>
  function checkValid(){
  var flg="Y";
    $.getJSON( "dynamic_content_values1.json", function( data ) {
        var textVal=$("#character_validation").val(); 
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            if(textVal===val.notificationID){
            flg="N";    
             return false; 
            }
      
    
    });
 if(flg==="N"){
            alert("ID Already Available!");
        }else{
            alert("Notification ID Available");
        }
  return false;
  });
        }
        </script>

Comment: First format your question properly. Add all code inside code sample <pre><code>. that way it will be easy for others to understand what you want. If possible provide a jsfiddle link.

Comment: <form method="post">
        <input type="text" id="character_validation" onblur="checkValid();" maxlength="10" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g, '')"><br>
        <input type="text">
       <!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="checkValid();">-->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

Comment: whats an issue here?

Comment: Vasim,  [{
 "notificationID": "kartik"
}, {
 "notificationID": "Keyan"
}]
This is a json file. As per the code if i type (Kartik or keyan) in first textbox and pressing tab, Validation is displayin that "Username is already available." Then im clicking Ok button from the alertbox and the cursor is going to second textbox. But i want cursor should be in first box itself after clickd OK button from alertbox

Comment: then you have ask in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this after alert statment,

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#character_validation").focus('');}, 1);
```

I have tried in JAVASCRIPT,

```
function IsUserExist(txtcontrol) { //txtcontrol means this
  if(txtcontrol.value == "2") {   
    alert("User Exist");
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('txtUserName').focus();
    }, 0);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: One more doubt: As per this function checkValid(), im able to validate the username from the json file and able to display the error message "NotificationId already available". For example, In JSON file im having value as KARTHIK, IF i give the same thing in database its showing Alert message. Suppose if i give karthik in lowercase validation is not working. Do we have any other options to validate uppercase and lowercase at a time?

Comment: You can use upper function before validate.

Comment: `str=txtcontrol.value;
var res = str.toUpperCase();`
you have to compate res with json response.that's it.

Comment: Thanks a lot vasim for your solution. Im facing one more issue that, Cursor in in first textbox and by mistake if i open new tab or open any editor for code modification, Alert message is showing continuously. Even if i click ok button also alert box is displaying continuously. Is this expected behavior or do we need any other solution

Comment: There is box "Prevent this dialog".. :)

Comment: After that you have new open it new window if you want to get alert back.

Comment: Overall code:                                                                                           function checkValid(){
var flg="Y";
$.getJSON( "dynamic_content_values1.json", function( data ) {
var textVal=$("#character_validation").val(); 
var upper_case = textVal.toUpperCase();
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
if(upper_case===val.notificationID){
flg="N";    
return false; 
}     
    
});
 if(flg==="N"){
alert("ID Already Available!");
setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById('character_validation').focus();
    }, 0);
 return false;
        }
});
}

Comment: write `debugger;` inside code and press F12 now refresh page.Press F10 and track step-by-step.

Comment: str=txtcontrol.value; var res = str.toUpperCase(); Vasim, As per this code, im able to validate Uppercase letter. Suppose if database value as Karthik or KARTHIK or KartikKeyan means the above code is not working. i mean mixed values are available in database means what logic do i use. please help me

Comment: You have convert both in same stream.Both in lower or both in upper case

Comment: var upper_case = textVal.toUpperCase()|| textVal.toLowerCase(); Im having multiple combinations like AB-100,ActualTotalCharges,AB-test2. How to convert these?